# Tranfer tokens out of a Smart contract

Tags: tokens, contract-debugging

I have been traying for days to make this work but i cannot really find a solution to this.
I tried several examples i found, included this: https://github.com/SmaCo/Tex/blob/fea52bc7f1cf01a8574ea3df2abcac6770bd8ade/TokenTransferEx.sol

I can transfer the token into the contract and see that are there (the token contract can see them aswell) but the method to withdraw them always fail. I have no idea how to debug this by the way.

For example this is the contract above i deployed and where i sent 5000 of my test tokens: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x838d49a113ff5ec7cf8deb8565c11716cd1c77fb#tokentxns

Anybody can explain what it may be the problem here?

Im using Metamask and https://remix.ethereum.org to run my test on ROPSTEN network

Comment: Your code appear to be right. Do you have a transaction  with the failure? Perhaps is something in the token contract.

Comment: the transaction is not even starting, remix is telling me that the gas estimation for the transferExternalToken is above the limit, symptom that something is really wrong. The token contract is just taken from here https://www.ethereum.org/token

Comment: I've tried your contract in remix with a dummy token and it works as expected. Are you passing the correct token address when you call `transferExternalTokenAllToOwner()`?

Comment: You should verify both contract sources on the Ethereum testnet and notify us. The issue may be inside the smart contract of the token you are trying to transfer instead of the contract you linked. One easy way I see the method failing is your contract **implementing the ERC-20 interface** but not returning a `bool` on successful execution.

Comment: Im starting to think it may be related with the decimal of that method somehow, even if i had tried several combinations even with very low values. What im sure is that is the transfer part that is failing and doesn't come through. I'll give another go and see if i can spot the problem @ismael can you link the contract you tested with the transactions going in and out, maybe i can spot something in there.